# True/False questions (from a real analysis course)

Tags: real-analysis

The source of these T/F problems is this.
http://www.math.drexel.edu/~rboyer/courses/math505/true_false1.pdf
(I am self-studying and found these problems by chance.)

Could you tell me if my answers are correct and give me some hints on the problem that I couldn't solve please?

1. No. There is also 0.
2. No. {n| n is a natural number} has no least upper bound.
3. Almost Yes. For all element a in A, a <= b  such that b is a supremum(A).
   Then for all a, 1/a >= 1/b. Hence, as long as b is not 0, it has a greatest lower
   bound.
4. Yes. Q is equal to the collection of Ai, Ai is the interval in Q.
   We know Q is countable, and each interval Ai is countable or has countable elements in 
   itself. Hence, there should be countable number of intervals.
5. Yes. There are countable number of Q in R, and there are countable number of Q in each 
   subset of R. so there should be countable collection of intervals.
6. No. Since rational number is dense in R, if there exists two irrational elements a and 
   b in an open subset of R(if there exists only one element, it is not open), we can 
   always find rational number between a and b.
7. Yes. By Lindelof's lemma
8. Yes. For example, subset : {1/2}, open cover: (0,1)
9. No. Counterexample: subset: {(0, 1/n) | n goes to infinity}
   Then its open cover should be the collection of (0, 1/n). It doesn't have finite 
   subcovers.
10. ?
11. ?

[image]

Comment: For 11.) Take any closed and bounded interval $[a, b]$.  Consider the cover $\{\{x\} : x \in [a, b]\}$

Comment: 3) is false, also in your argument you have to prove that exist an $c$ such that $a>=c$ for all $a\in A$ not $1/a>=c$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$3.$ is false. Take $(-\infty,0)$

$5.$ is false. Each interval in $\Bbb R$ is uniquely determined by its endpoints.

$9.$ is oddly phrased. Any arbitrary subset has the trivial finite cover $\{\Bbb R\}$.

$10.$ is Heine-Borel.

$11.$ is false. Take $[0,1]$, and cover it by the compacts $$\left\{\left[0,1-\frac1n \right]:n=2,3,\ldots\right\}\cup\{\{1\}\}$$

Answer (score 3):

Actually, number 6 is true (the empty set).